# Confusion in friendly_id instructions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

the application has installed per gemfile.lock

```
friendly_id (5.1.0)
friendly_id-globalize (1.0.0.alpha2)
```

the [base gem page states](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) "As of version 5.0, Finders are no longer overridden by default. If you want to do friendly finds, you must do Model.friendly.find"
  while the guide for 5.1 links to [the most complete, user-friendly documentation,](http://norman.github.io/friendly_id/file.Guide.html) which states both following forms are possible:

```
Person.find(82542335)
Person.friendly.find("joe")
```

Compounding matters the [globalize plugin](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id-globalize)  also refers to a compact syntactic version

```
I18n.locale = :en
Post.find("star-wars")
```

So there are a few possibilities so wrangle with.  The following model set-up:

```
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :slug, :use => :globalize
```

and associated controller action

```
  def show
    @staticpage = Staticpage.find(params[:slug])
    @the_page = Staticpage.find(2)
```

only has the find(#{id}) instance variable working, whereas all syntaxes attempted on the first instance variable invariably returns `Couldn't find Staticpage with 'id'=`

While a working answer would be appreciated, a clarification of uses would be better!

Comment: I am not certain but I'd suspect the readme for `friendly_id-globalize` hasn't been updated in line with friendly_id 5.  In your example code it may not be working because friendly_id overrides `to_param` so it uses the slug as the id in rails.  So you want `@staticpage = Staticpage.find(params[:id])` if you've not explicitly passed slug as a parameter to the controller.

Comment: That is a small step.`"id"=>"refrigerazione-condizioni"}` is being passed as a parameter.  However AR does not digest it properly: `Couldn't find Staticpage with 'id'=refrigerazione-condizioni`.  Attempting, according to the > 5.0 instructions `@staticpage = Staticpage.friendly.find(params[:id])` returns `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`

Comment: Did you set the locale to the correct locale before running the find?

Comment: Yes, it is set by an application-wide method.  As an added bit of info, for example the edit action using what was the original set-up without friendly_id: `@staticpage = Staticpage.find_by_slug!(params[:slug])`properly returns the page

Comment: @j-dexx  the locale suggestion pointed in the proper general direction.  As this was dealing with pre-existing data, the slug field was populated.  slug_en not.  So, somehow the database needs to be updated with the required values before proceeding (and in the meantime the finds are *not* working => vicious circle!)... which is another issue.